# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error - Fruit detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having an error running my fruit detection model. Do you have any idea why? You can see the error after the code. How can I fix this problem? I need this for a school project, so i would be happy about fast answers :))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Users\\XX\\Desktop\\XX\\2. Semester\\Data Science\\archive'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array, load_img
train_path = "C:\\Users\\XX\\Desktop\\XX\\2. Semester\\Data Science\\archive\\train_zip\\train"
test_path = "C:\\Users\\XX\\Desktop\\XX\\2. Semester\\Data Science\\archive\\test_zip\\test"


img = load_img(train_path + "\\litchi\\280_100.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis("on")
plt.show()

img = img_to_array(img)
img.shape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,100,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.50))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5000, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(131, activation = "softmax"))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD", metrics=["accuracy"])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                   shear_range=0.3,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=False,
                                   zoom_range=0.3
                                   )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                    target_size=(100, 100),
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    color_mode="rgb",
                                                    class_mode="categorical")
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                  target_size=(100, 100),
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  color_mode="rgb",
                                                  class_mode="categorical")

hist = model.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch = 50,
                   epochs = 50,
                   validation_data = test_generator,
                   validation_steps = 50)

from keras.models import load_model
model.save("Fruitmodel.h5")

import tensorflow as tf
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model,
                                         tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
test_generator.classes[1460]

predictions = probability_model.predict(test_generator)
b=predictions[8]
print(b)

np.argmax(b)

import os

folder = 'C:\\Users\\XX\\Desktop\\XX\\2. Semester\\Data Science\\archive\\test_zip\\test'

sub_folders = [name for name in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, name))]

print(sub_folders[3]) ```

# Error: InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error #

```Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 328, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2863, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2909, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3309, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14720\1719248090.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
      runfile('C:/Users/Janine/Desktop/DHBW/2. Semester/Projekt.py', wdir='C:/Users/Janine/Desktop/DHBW/2. Semester')
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 577, in runfile
      exec_code(file_code, filename, ns_globals, ns_locals,
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 465, in exec_code
      exec(compiled, ns_globals, ns_locals)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\Desktop\DHBW\2. Semester\Projekt.py", line 59, in <module>
      hist = model.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2260, in fit_generator
      return self.fit(
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 890, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\Janine\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5134, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,131] labels_size=[32,3]
     [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2419]```
````

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual error is this:

```
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,131] labels_size=[32,3]
```

Try to change this line:

```
model.add(Dense(131, activation = "softmax"))
```

to this:

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation = "softmax"))
```